# Chatter @Mention In Community

Tags: apex, chatter, community

Is there a way to specify a particular community when creating a Chatter post in the Connect API using Apex? `EntitySubscription` etc. have a `NetworkId`field for connecting things to particular communities, but the only methods I can see that are community related are for reading some basic information about the communities available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, almost every Connect API (Chatter REST API) endpoint supports communities. For posting a feed item to your news feed, the URL has this form:

```
/connect/communities/<communityId>/chatter/feeds/news/me/feed-items
```

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/intro_building_url.htm for more information.

Using the ConnectApi namespace in Apex, almost all of the methods include the network/community ID as the first parameter. For the posting example, one of the methods you could use is `ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(String communityId, ConnectApi.FeedType feedType, String subjectId, String text)`

Comment: Ah, I should have been more specific. I meant using the Connect API from Apex, not REST.

Comment: Using the ConnectApi namespace in Apex, almost all of the methods include the network/community ID as the first parameter. For the posting example, one of the methods you could use is ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(String communityId, ConnectApi.FeedType feedType, String subjectId, String text).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I was looking at older docs!